# Read a space character from an XML element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, whitespace

A surprisingly simple question this time! :-) There's an XML file like this:

```
<xml>
  <data> </data>
</xml>
```

Now I need to read exactly whatever is in the `<data>` element. Be it a single whitespace like U+0020. My naive guess:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(fileName);
XmlNode xn = xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("data");
string data = xn.InnerText;
```

But that returns an **empty string**. The white space got lost. Any other data can be read just fine.

What do I need to do to get my space character here?

After browsing the web for a while, I tried reading the XML file with an XmlReader that lets me set `XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = false` but that didn't help.

Comment: This might be a behaviour of the nonstandard `InnerText` property. Have you tried reading the child text nodes directly?

Comment: I had not, but now I have, and there is no text node for a single whitespace in the document. The solution with xml:space below works well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `xml:space="preserve"` in your XML, according to the W3C standards and the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f00zs65%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> The W3C standards dictate that white space be handled differently
>   depending on where in the document it occurs, and depending on the
>   setting of the xml:space attribute. If the characters occur within the
>   mixed element content or inside the scope of the xml:space="preserve",
>   they must be preserved and passed without modification to the
>   application. Any other white space does not need to be preserved. The
>   XmlTextReader only preserves white space that occurs within an
>   xml:space="preserve" context.

```
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.LoadXml(@"<xml xml:space=""preserve""><data> </data></xml>");
        XmlNode xn = xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("data");
        string data = xn.InnerText; // data == " "
        Console.WriteLine(data == " "); //True
```

Tested [HERE](http://ideone.com/H7AstJ).